# Fine line between kickstart and puppet

Tags: linux, puppet, kickstart

I'm interested in Puppet configuration management system, but wonder where the fine line goes between kick-start and Puppet?

Today I do a lot of tasks in kick-start (powered by Cobbler), including some custom partitioning.

Question is, if better to move everything (except custom partitioning and puppet packages) into Puppet, for a more flexible management? Or there are some defined guidelines for this?

Thanks.

Comment: I just answered this question here:

http://serverfault.com/questions/98872/scripted-install-vs-cloning/98874#98874

Comment: So it's as I said -  do the partition + install Puppet, then do all the rest from the Puppet scripts?

Just a quick question - can Puppet manage installed repos?

Thanks.

Comment: Puppet can do anything you can do manually.  Sometimes the trick is teaching puppet how to do something idempotently.  ie, you can't just tell it to add a repo, you also need to give it a way to check to see if the repo is already added.  puppet makes this pretty easy though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need a baseline system with puppet on it to allow puppet to start managing the system. So you should use kickstart to do the base install (with the puppet packages) then use puppet to configure the rest of the system. They are complimentary not competitive technologies.